# Multiple commands from two lists

Tags: bash

Is there a simpler way how to generate multiple command lines from two lists?

```
for project in `cat projectlist.txt`;do
  for user in `cat userlist.txt`; do
    echo remove $user from $project
  done
done
```

**userlist.txt**

```
user1 user2 user3 user4 user5 user6 user7
```

**projectlist.txt**

```
project1 project2 project3 project4 project5 project6 project7 project8 project9
```

Comment: There are other ways, but I don't know about "simpler". Those loops look pretty simple to me, no?

Comment: I agree with @JohnKugelman. If you have an idea already, or some concerns about your current solution, please let us know.

Comment: Is there a way how to do it as oneliner without creating two separate list-files and then iterate over it? Thanks